# One to many with MongoDB (Mongoose) with .populate()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

##### What I am doing

I am trying to return a player by playerId with all ref items from each object in it's schema. In this example, I am specifically talking about the players inventory.

How can I return all reference items and their properties?

In my service file, I am getting my player with:

```
/**
 * Get a player by playerId
 * @param playerId
 * @returns {Promise<*>}
 */
module.exports.getPlayer = async (playerId) => {
  return await Player.findOne({ playerId: playerId }).populate('inventory');
};
```

###### And this is my returned JSON

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "_id": "63bb1f3ec17d33f4d2a87194",
        "playerId": 4183489039,
        "name": "AlanGreyjoy",
        "currency": {
            "copper": 500,
            "silver": 10,
            "gold": 0
        },
        "online": false,
        "inventory": [
            {
                "currentDurability": 0,
                "item": "63ba0c54407456969ba38615",
                "amount": 1,
                "_id": "63bc4fa070eaa247288e3573",
                "createdAt": "2023-01-09T17:32:16.643Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-01-09T17:32:16.643Z"
            }
        ],
        "bank": [],
        "questTracker": [],
        "friends": [],
        "knownRecipes": [],
        "jobs": [],
        "createdAt": "2023-01-08T19:53:34.903Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-01-09T17:32:16.643Z",
        "__v": 1
    }
}
```

As you can see, the item in the inventory array is not populating with the ref item from the items collection.

I have googled and googled and tried so many different things, but nothing is working.\

The item does exist in the db
[image]

##### My Models

My Player.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const toJSON = require('../plugins/mongoToJson');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const questTracker = new Schema(
  {
    quest: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Quest' },
    complete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const friends = new Schema(
  {
    player: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' },
    isFavorite: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const knownRecipes = new Schema(
  {
    recipe: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe' },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const jobs = new Schema(
  {
    job: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Job' },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const inventoryItems = new Schema(
  {
    item: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' },
    amount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    currentDurability: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const bank = new Schema(
  {
    item: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' },
    amount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const playerSchema = new Schema(
  {
    playerId: {
      type: Number,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    currency: {
      type: Object,
      default: {
        copper: 500,
        silver: 10,
        gold: 0,
      },
    },
    inventory: [inventoryItems],
    bank: [bank],
    questTracker: [questTracker],
    friends: [friends],
    knownRecipes: [knownRecipes],
    jobs: [jobs],
    online: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const PlayerModel = mongoose.model('player', playerSchema);

module.exports = PlayerModel;
```

My Item.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const toJSON = require('../plugins/mongoToJson');

const vendorPriceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  copper: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  silver: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  gold: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
});

const itemSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    assetId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
    equipDescription: {
      type: String,
    },
    additionalDescription: {
      type: String,
    },
    consumableUseDescription: {
      type: String,
    },
    itemLevel: {
      type: Number,
    },
    requiredLevel: {
      type: Number,
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    subtype: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    stamina: {
      type: Number,
    },
    intellect: {
      type: Number,
    },
    criticalStrike: {
      type: Number,
    },
    agility: {
      type: Number,
    },
    mastery: {
      type: Number,
    },
    maxDurability: {
      type: Number,
    },
    vendorPrice: { vendorPriceSchema },
    minDamage: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    maxDamage: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    speed: {
      type: Number,
    },
    maxStack: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const ItemModel = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);

module.exports = ItemModel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
module.exports.getPlayer = async (playerId) => {
  return await Player.findOne({ playerId: playerId }).populate({
      path: "inventory",
      populate: {
        path: "item",
      },
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the same result was returned as above :(

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: So, I lower cased path: "Item" to "item" and it worked!!!!! Thank you very much. The mongo docs for populate() are 10 miles long haha.